# Java Downcasting/Upcasting

Tags: java, inheritance

I am getting ClassCastEception in the following code.
Me class extends the person class. why can't i downcast the Me object to Person.  I can't understand the logic here. please anyone make me clear with good explanation.

```
public class Conv {

    public class Person {
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String name = "X";
        public Person(String n) {
            name = n;
        }
        /*
         * many other variables and procedures
         */
    }

    public class Me extends Person {
        /*
         * nothing more in this class
         */
        public Me(String n) {
            super(n);
        }
    }
    public void test() {
        Person p = new Person("Roy");
        Me a = (Me) p;
        System.out.println(a.name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Conv().test();
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Person` class may have methods, variables that the `Me` class doesn't have.

Comment: You are cast a `Person` to a type it is not `Me`.  This is not allowed in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Every Cat is an Animal. But not every Animal is a Cat. Same rule applies here. You cannot turn every `Person` to `Me`. Where as every `Me` is a `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating `p` as `new Person`, not `new Me`. For casting, it's the runtime type that is checked. If you create `Person p = new Me("Roy")`, then you can cast it to `Me` because in reality (during runtime) even though it's declared as `Person`, it is a `Me`.